# Error when drawing rectangle with color sent as a parameter OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I have an 1000x1000px image which I want to divide into 10x10 px squares. I have the variable "coordenada" to track the coords of the current 10x10 square (that's why when trying to get the x and y values I multiply by 10).

I want to draw a rectangle surrounding the "current" 10x10 square given by the coords. I get corner 1 (p1) by multiplying the coords by 10 and corner 2 (p2) by doing the same and adding 10. I want the color of the frame to be the same as the color it has in the middle of the square, so I access that color using canvas[x, y], canvas being the name of the image loaded in a numpy array, and typecasting it into a tuple since that is what I read I need to send cv.rectangle. This is the resulting code (minus declaration of canvas and coordenada):

```
p1 = (coordenada[0] * 10, coordenada[1] * 10)
p2 = (coordenada[0] * 10 + 10, coordenada[1] * 10 + 10)
colorOfFrame = tuple(canvas[(coordenada[0]*10 + 5), (coordenada[1]*10 + 5)])
# testColor = (255, 123, 32)
cv2.rectangle(canvas, p1, p2, colorOfFrame, 2)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error message:

```
    cv2.rectangle(canvas, p1, p2, colorOfFrame, 2)
TypeError: function takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

I have tried many argument combinations (like sending a rec instead of two points, etc) and the only way I can get it to work is if the tuple I send as the color is defined using constant values, hence the testColor variable. I have seen many examples online where color is sent as a tuple created by functions the same way I did. What is wrong with this way?

Apologies for my english. I'll add the complete code at the end of the question. The idea is to use a Paint-like program where you can draw shapes using a cursor controlled by keyboard on a 100x100 "pixel" area. Color of the pencil is defined as a list and modified by pressing either I, O or P keys, and the cursor is controlled using W A S D. To keep track of where the cursor is, I draw a frame around the pixel and when a movement key is pressed, that frame is deleted (hence the need to draw a rectangle of the inner color), the cursor is modified and then the new frame is drawn. It is very much a work in progress but my work has stop with this error.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

canvas = np.zeros((1000, 1000, 3), np.uint8)
canvas = cv2.bitwise_not(canvas)

coordenada = [0, 0]
coordenadasMax = (99, 99)
dibujando = False
cruz = False
color = [255, 255, 255]


def dibujar_pixel():
    if dibujando:
        cv2.rectangle(canvas, (coordenada[0] * 10, coordenada[1] * 10), (coordenada[0] * 10 + 10, coordenada[1] * 10 + 10), color, -1)
    else:
        cv2.rectangle(canvas, (coordenada[0] * 10, coordenada[1] * 10), (coordenada[0] * 10 + 10, coordenada[1] * 10 + 10), color, 2)


def borrar_pixel():
    if not dibujando:
        p1 = (coordenada[0] * 10, coordenada[1] * 10)
        p2 = (coordenada[0] * 10 + 10, coordenada[1] * 10 + 10)
        colorOfFrame = canvas[(coordenada[0]*10 + 5), (coordenada[1]*10 + 5)]
        testColor = (255, 123, 32)
        cv2.rectangle(canvas, p1, p2, colorOfFrame, 2)


cv2.imshow("Canvas", canvas)

while True:
    tecla = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if tecla == 13:  # enter para cambiar entre dibujar o no dibujar
        dibujando = not dibujando

    elif tecla == ord("a"):  # a para ir a la izquierda
        borrar_pixel()
        if coordenada[0] == 0:  # wrapAround si está en el borde izquierdo
            coordenada[0] = coordenadasMax[0]
        else:
            coordenada[0] -= 1
        dibujar_pixel()

    elif tecla == ord("d"):  # d para ir a la derecha
        borrar_pixel()
        if coordenada == coordenadasMax[0]:  # wrapAround si está en el borde derecho
            coordenada[0] = 0
        else:
            coordenada[0] += 1
        dibujar_pixel()

    elif tecla == ord("w"):  # w para ir hacia arriba
        borrar_pixel()
        if coordenada[1] == 0:  # wrapAround si está en el borde superior
            coordenada[1] = coordenadasMax[1]
        else:
            coordenada[1] -= 1
        dibujar_pixel()

    elif tecla == ord("s"):
        borrar_pixel()
        if coordenada[1] == coordenadasMax[1]:
            coordenada[1] = 0
        else:
            coordenada[1] += 1
        dibujar_pixel()

    elif tecla == ord("m"):
        cruz = not cruz

    elif tecla == 21:
        break

    elif tecla == ord("i"):
        if color[0] == 255:
            color[0] = 0
        else:
            color[0] = 255
        dibujar_pixel()

    elif tecla == ord("o"):
        if color[1] == 255:
            color[1] = 0
        else:
            color[1] = 255
        dibujar_pixel()

    elif tecla == ord("p"):
        if color[2] == 255:
            color[2] = 0
        else:
            color[2] = 255
        dibujar_pixel()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message seems misleading -- it looks like the `TypeError` stems from `colorOfFrame` tuple not consisting of `int` elements (it consists of `np.uint8`'s).

You can avoid the error by explicitly casting pixel values to `int`. Here is one way to do this:

```
colorOfFrame = tuple(int(c) for c in canvas[(coordenada[0]*10 + 5), (coordenada[1]*10 + 5)])
cv2.rectangle(canvas, p1, p2, colorOfFrame, 2)
```